# React frontend calling API with self-signed-certificate through axios

Tags: reactjs, ssl, axios, self-signed-certificate

I'm having trouble making requests from my frontend to an API which has self-signed-certificates.

I have a React frontend that allows to download videos from a backend. Videos are actually stored on IoT devices.
To save bandwidth, the frontend tries to detect if it's on the same local network of the device where the video is (it's local IP is known). If it is, it downloads the video directly from it (the device has a HTTP server) instead of downloading it from the backend.

That works very well with HTTP. However, I cannot use HTTP when my website runs on HTTPS, because of the `mixed content` rule.

I made the HTTP servers of my devices run on HTTPS too, and use a **self-signed certificate** that they generate on start. Then, I thought I could use this on the specific call in the frontend so that these are allowed by the browser:

```
axios.create({
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    }),
  })
```

However, The browser still refuse to proceed. What am I missing ?

I also tested most tricks from https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/535, and also to use a simple `fetch` This seems not to work with React.

Comment: Why we cannot ignore SSL verification from front end alone, this is possible by making the API call from node js(which is backend). All the answers point to ignoring the backend alone and not the front end. Any luck?